# To get value from Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code i am passing json object it is in the format {"Table":[{"FAMin":0,"FAMax":40,"FAGrade":"C"}]}.How to get the value from it i tried the below code it results undefined .Pls help me to overcome this issue.

```
 function UpdateGrade(GradeID) {
        alert(GradeID);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //HTTP method
            url: "MarkorGradeSettings.aspx/GetGrade", //page/method name
            data: "{'GradeID':'" + GradeID + "'}", //json to represent argument
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);// I get values 
                var parsedJson = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                alert(parsedJson.Table.FAMin);//undefined

                //handle the callback to handle response                
                if (msg != 'error') {
                    //$('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response);
                    // OP requested to close the modal
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response);
                }

                //Now add the new items to the dropdown.

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to use `Parse` the variable to JSON, as it is already in JSON format as you've used `dataType: "json",` in AJAX config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed that the data under `Table` is an array.

This should at least fix this particular case:

`alert(parsedJson.Table[0].FAMin);`

Answer (score 1):

`Table` is an array but you are treating as an object

Try:

```
alert(msg.d.Table[0].FAMin)
```

Also as noted in comments there is no need to call `jQuery.parseJSON` when `dataType:'json'` is set. jQuery will parse the response internally and return object/array in callback